# XSLT sort by date show most recent issue

Tags: xml, xslt

I am trying to display the most recent item returned only.

I have the following code:

```
<xsl:choose>
<xsl:when test="(count(Customer/TABLE[@NAME='T1']/TABLE[@NAME='T2']/TABLE[@NAME='T3']/TABLE[@NAME='T4']/RECORDS/RECORD) >= 1)">          
<xsl:for-each select="Customer/TABLE[@NAME='T1']/TABLE[@NAME='T2']/TABLE[@NAME='T3']/TABLE[@NAME='T4']/RECORDS/RECORD">
<xsl:sort select="COLUMN[@NAME='DATE_START']/@VALUE" order="ascending"/>
<xsl:if test="position() = last()">
<tr>
    <td class="alltext" style="text-align:center;">
        <xsl:value-of select="COLUMN[@NAME='DATE_START']/@VALUE" />
    </td> 
    <td class="alltext" style="text-align:center;">
        <xsl:value-of select="COLUMN[@NAME='STATUS']/@VALUE_DESCRIPTION" />
    </td> 
    <td class="alltext" style="text-align:center;">
        <xsl:value-of select="COLUMN[@NAME='REASON']/@VALUE_DESCRIPTION" />
    </td> 
    <td class="alltext" style="text-align:center;"> 
        <xsl:value-of select="COLUMN[@NAME='TRUSTED']/@VALUE_DESCRIPTION" />
    </td> 
</tr>
</xsl:if>
</xsl:for-each> 
</xsl:when>
<xsl:otherwise>
```

It always shows 1 result but not always the latest result.

The field datatype in the database is datetime but I'm guessing it's sorting by text string.

I tried after looking for a solution to convert to date:

```
<xsl:variable name="dt" as="xs:dateTime" select="xs:dateTime(COLUMN[@NAME='DATE_START']/@VALUE)"/>
<xsl:sort select="format-dateTime($dt, '[Y0001]/[M01]/[D01]')" order="ascending"/>
```

In the place of:

```
<xsl:sort select="COLUMN[@NAME='DATE_START']/@VALUE" order="ascending"/>
```

But I receive error:

> An Error has occured
>
> The following error occured when transforming your document
>
> XSLT compile error at (803,29).

Line 803 is:

```
<xsl:variable name="dt" as="xs:dateTime" select="xs:dateTime(COLUMN[@NAME='DATE_EMP_STAT_APP']/@VALUE)"/>
```

Any help much appreciated.

I'm likely to be a million miles off...

```
XSLT Version 1
```

Many thanks

Comment: `<xsl:variable name="dt" as="xs:dateTime" select="xs:dateTime(COLUMN[@NAME='DATE_EMP_STAT_APP']/@VALUE)"/>` is XSLT 2.0 (both the `as` attribute as well as the `xs:dateTime` constructor) so it is never going to work with an XSLT 1.0 processor.

Comment: Ok thanks. That explains that error then. The example I found I'm sure it stated v1. Thanks

Comment: Sorting YYYY-MM-DD dates as text should work - please post an example of an input where it doesn't.

Comment: A customer has 2 dates. 24/06/2016 00:00:00 and 11/08/2017 00:00:00. I would want the record with date 11/08/2017 00:00:00 to be shown but it shows the older...